# Books/Author suggestions?

Tags: reference-request

I highly enjoyed Aldous Huxley's and Alan Watts' books on Philosophy : for example, Huxley's *The Divine Within* and *The Perennial Philosophy* and Watts's *Become What You Are*, *This Is It*, *The Book*, and *Behold the Spirit*.

Both writers are highly intellectual and their theme is more or less the same. Huxley writes elegantly and absorbs the reader and makes valid points. Watts, on the other hand, writes very simply and tells it like it is. No beating around the bush.

Question: Can anyone recommend any similar authors to these two on the subject?

Comment: Both Will Rodgers and Bertrand Russell wrote very readable and informative works on the History of Western Philosophy.

Comment: Nice! Recommend any specific titles from them? ...

Comment: Sorry, the titles are both, "The History of Western Philosophy". Visit the ZLibrary for free downloads. Regards,

Comment: You might enjoy Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance, by Robert Pirsig.

Comment: Great, thanks Charles/Mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will very likely enjoy Hermann Hesse's many philosophical novels, for instance,   *Narcissus and Goldmund;
Siddhartha;
Demian;
Steppenwolf;
The Journey to the East;
Magister Ludi: The Glass Bead Game.*

You might also enjoy W.Somerset Maugham's *The Razor's Edge*, and one or another of John Fowle's novels, for instance, *The *Maggot**, *A Magus* and *Daniel Martin*.

I read these long ago.  About the same time I was reading Huxley and Watts.

**Addendum:**  @Mark Andrews mentioned  Persig's  *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance*,  a good one from that 60s/70s/80s era,   but very different from the metaphysical novels of the English author "types" which were the focus of the OP.

But if we're gonna include Persig's opus in the relevant category, I would also mention:

Richard Bach's *Jonathan Livingston Seagull*, and, especially, his later book, *Illusions*;

Tom Robbin's *Even Cowgirls Get the Blues*, *Another Roadside Attraction*;  and *Still Life With Woodpecker*; and, finally;

Joseph Chilton Pearce's *The Crack in the Cosmic Egg*: *Challenging Constructs of Mind and Reality.*

Comment: Great suggestions! Thanks so much. Helps that you have also read those 2 already.

Comment: Your welcome.  My pleasure.  you may also be aware that years ago Alan Watts did a bunch of recordings of  lectures and talks, which have been compiled and you can purchase here:  https://www.alanwatts.org/audio/

Comment: Oh yes I already have most of his audio talks - Out of Your Mind. Will see if the link you sent has any others that I am missing. Watts is pretty amazing!

Comment: Jesse's 'Journey to the East' is another.

Comment: Of all these authors, who writes in a simple manner? (like Watts). I hope none of them are old-English as they are hard to read!

Comment: Hesse's writing might be considered the simplest.   But gotta say, all of them are twentieth century writers, that is, none of them write in old english.  I would say they all write more or less at the level of neither Watts and Huxley, who are not necessarily "simple" writers.

Comment: @Steve237- Karl Jaspers produced a wonderful series called something like, 'The Great Philosophers'

Comment: @Gonzo: I noticed many of the books you sited are mostly novels. Which are non-novels? (such as the few I mentioned in the original question).

Comment: @Steve237 all are novels whose foray into philosophy are akin to those of the the books and authors (Watts and Huxley) you mentioned.

Comment: Noted, Thx! Huxley's style, and the affect he has on me is no different than listening to a classical music - it's so enjoyable and deep. Huston Smith paraphrased one from him which became my most favorite: "He loved the desert...for its symbolic power. Its emptiness emptied the mind. The boundlessness of its sand spreads a mantle of sameness - hence unity over the world's multiplicity in the way snow does. The Nothingness in which the desert fathers were drawn is not a blank negation. it is no-thing-ness in which everything is so interfused that divisions are transcended. ...."

Comment: Though I've not read him in decades, I too was once upon a time moved by his prose.  I do hope and trust that you will appreciate particularly the Hesse and Maugham novels.